# How to generate unique id for each tokens without using loop?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

I'm creating tokens without use of any pre-defined standard. As we have requirement to track each token, I did code to assigned ids to each token.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract MyContract {

    string Name;
    string Symbol;

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    mapping (address => Counters.Counter) private _ownedTokensCount;        
    mapping (uint256 => address) private _tokenOwner;

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _totalSupply) public {
        Name = _name;
        Symbol = _symbol;


        for(uint256 i=1; i<= _totalSupply; i++){
            _tokenOwner[i] = msg.sender;
        }

        _ownedTokensCount[msg.sender].incrementBySupply(_totalSupply);               
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public {

        _ownedTokensCount[from].decrement();
        _ownedTokensCount[to].increment();

        _tokenOwner[tokenId] = to;
    }

    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256) {

        return _ownedTokensCount[owner].current();
    }

    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address) {
        address owner = _tokenOwner[tokenId];        
        return owner;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
        return Name;
    }

    function getSymbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return Symbol;
    }
}
```

The code is working fine when we pass lower number of total supply. But as increasing total supply, it will run out of gas. So, my question is, Is there any alternate way to generate unique ids for tokens without loop?

**Full requirement:**

I'm taking an example of an artist market place to clear up the requirement.

Roles:
- Artist
- Fans

Artists can create tokens for them using a smart contact.

Leonardo, for example, created tokens LEO with a total supply of 1000. So, currently his wallet is holding 1000 LEO tokes.

Fans can purchase tokens from an artist. I'm a fan of Leonardo, so I'll purchase some tokens from him and give some fiat currency to him. Let's say I've purchased 100 tokens from him.

Now, an artist can create a reward and sell it. For example, Leonardo has created one painting reward with a value of 50 tokens.

I've claimed that reward on 9-Apr-2020, so my 50 tokens have been used and that 50 tokens I can not be used till 3 months(9-July-2020)

There is no limit to creating reward by an artist. Now suppose Leonardo has created another reward for 1 token. And I have claimed it on 10-Apr-2020, now that 1 token from my balance is on hold for three months till 10-July-2020, and my available balance is 49 Leo tokens.

During this time, I can sell all the tokens(49+1+50) to another user (let's take a name, Alex). But the tokens are on hold will be transferred with dates, meaning that Alex can't use 50+1 token till its holding ends.

Comment: Instead of mapping each token to an owner, map each owner to a list of tokens.

Comment: ERC721 seems similar to your task. Did you take a look at it?

Comment: @Ismael yes, but I'm not sure if ERC721 allowing for the batch operation. I want to create thousands of tokens for the users.

Comment: @Div Do you have any other requirement? One possibility is to have "virtual" tokens, the tokens are created only when they are transferred. For example you can reserve a range of ids to a user, when one is transferred the user pays to create it.

Comment: @Ismael I have added requirement details to the question.

Comment: @Div It is similar to an ERC20 with a locking mechanism. The locked tokens create some strange situations: if you locked 50 tokens of 100 and transfer 20, which tokens are transferred? the locked ones or the unlocked. Obviously the unlocked ones appear to be more expensive.

Comment: @goodvibration That could still end up in out-of-gas exceptions for too many tokens.

Comment: @Div Reading over your requirements, it sounds to me like you can do that without unique ids, just remembering the amount of locked tokens.